# JPA entity updated only after method is done

Tags: jpa, asynchronous, merge, entity

I have an Asynchronous annotated method which receives an entity though the method parameter. In this method I try to set a variable three times:

```
@Inject EntityDao entityDao;

@Asynchronous
public Future<String> doSomething (MyEntity p_myEntity) {

    MyEntity myEntity = entityDao.merge(p_myEntity); // change from detached to attached
    // em.contains(myEntity) returns true

    myEntity.setName("Joe 1"); // newer set in database
    // A System.out.println(myEntity.getName()) does say "Joe 1"

    try {
        Thread.sleep(20*1000);
    } catch () ...etc

    myEntity.setName("Joe 2"); // newer set in database
    // A System.out.println(myEntity.getName()) does say "Joe 2"

    try {
        Thread.sleep(20*1000);
    } catch () ...etc

    myEntity.setName("Joe 3"); // only one set in database

    return new AsyncResult<>("done");
}
```

**Edit**: So thanks to PedroKowalski I have a better understanding of the problem and I will reformulate.

During the execution of the above method, I have two ways of checking if the myEntity.setName() is actually changed:

- During the sleep() I check the database if the name value is changed
- On a webpage the list of MyEntity objects are displayed (with the names), this list is being updated every 2 seconds.

Both of the above methods indicate that the values "Joe 1" and "Joe 2" are newer in the database. Only after the doSomething() method is done, the last name set (Joe 3) is being put in the database.

So my question is: why are the values "Joe 1" and "Joe 2" not put in the database and only the last value is put in the database?

Comment: Is this another method a part of the same transaction? Did you try flushing the EM explicitly after the merging occurs?

Comment: No, not the same transaction. You mean flushing everytime after merge() in the EntityDao?

Comment: What do you mean by 'i'm calling the myEntity.getName() method'. Is this the same instance you pass to the 'doSomething' method or is it an instance of MyEntity looked up using EntityManager#findById(-) ?

Comment: No, somewhere else in a controller class I am retrieving all of myEntities by calling entityDao.findAll(), and display them on a webpage. This is done every 5 seconds. To make it clear: the Asynchronous method and the controller have nothing to do with each other

Comment: You can set all the values you want and merge at the end of the method. You can also merge at the beginning of the method and set all the values you want after it (on the object instance returned from merge() instance). It doesn't matter, however, you need to invoke a merge operation at least one, as you are operating on detached entity in this method.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you use JTA transactions than the transaction boundary spreads from method's begin to its end.

Therefore, changes made in an **active** transaction T1 can't be seen in transaction T2. If you think about it, it's quite reasonable.
Assume that T2 could operate on data which was changed by T1 but **not committed**.  Upon T1 rollback, every changes made to the entities in T1 must be invalidated. You've ended in a situation in which T2 operated on invalid data.

That's why you won't see 'Joe 1' (this value is changed only in T1) from any transaction other than T1. You can only see 'Joe 2' when methods ends (T1 commits).

The [EntityManager#flush()](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/EntityManager.html#flush%28%29) synchronizes the data with the underlying database but **does not commit it**. For more detailed information you can see this thread: http://www.java.net/node/665442#comment-678155

I can see three solutions in this case:

1. Optimistic locking could save you from situations in which two transactions T1 and T2 change the same data (the same entity). In case you have no locking, only the last committed transaction changes will be reflected in the database (so you've changes made by the former transaction are lost). With locking, you will get an Exception in the last committed transaction, so no data will be lost.
2. Pessimistic locking could lock the data for the time of modification. In this case, your transaction T2 would not operate on the data until T1 finishes.
3. At last - the most simple situation is (if possible) just to separate your method to smaller chunks.

HTH.

Comment: I'm not using JTA transaction, or am I? The only JTA related code is in my persistence.xml: <persistence-unit name="com.bla.PU" transaction-type="JTA">. I am not starting/committing any transaction on my own. The methods described in the OP are not surrounded by a transaction.

Comment: The relevant part you shown is the JTA usage declaration. Because you use the JTA you don't have any start/commit code for transactions. If you would use RESOURCE_LOCAL transaction-type than you would need to set the boundaries of the transaction by explicitly using start/commit. As said, by default JTA transaction starts at the method begin and ends upon commit.

Comment: Thank you :) If anyone wants to add information go ahead. Meanwhile I will set this as the answer.

Comment: Do you have a link to documentation which explains that the JTA transaction starts at the method begin and ends upon commit?

Comment: Take a look at this: http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bncij.html and this: http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bnciy.html

Comment: I thought of another solution but it didn't work: call a method within doSomething() that is annotated with @TransactionAttribute(TransactionAttributeType.REQUIRES_NEW). In that method I could set the name for MyEntity. Why doesn't that work?

Comment: @BigJ remember that nested transactions are not allowed. Therefore, if you invoke a method with REQUIRES_NEW TransactionAttributeType than you're suspending the current transaction, T1, of doSomething() method and create new transaction - T2. When T2 finsihes, T1 is resumed. I don't think it would help you in your case :-(

Comment: So as a conclusion: when a method A is called (on a session bean with JTA transactions enabled), this method, and all the methods called within method A form one big transaction?

Comment: I've just tested it and yes, it looks like this is one big transaction; i.e. if T1 starts -> T1 invokes separate method which starts T2 -> T2 commits -> T1 rollback. In this case changes made by T2 will not be visible at the end. What's interesting is what was said before - the T2 can read data changed by T1.

Comment: Wow, I also tested it and indeed: T2 can read changed data by T1, while other methods outside T1 can't. Amazing. (though not helping my initial problem haha)

Comment: @BigJ was thinking about your problem. What might help you is the usage of Extended Persistence Context from a SFSB. If you share the same EntityManager than you will have access to the PersistenceContext even before transaction commit.

Answer (score 0):

> So my question is: why are the values "Joe 1" and "Joe 2" not put in
>   the database and only the last value is put in the database?

- Data is written to the database during em.flush().  Data is visible to other users/persistence contexts when the transaction is commited.
- You do not manually flush to the database via em.flush(), so em.flush() is automatically called when the transaction is committed.
- The transaction is committed at the end of your method, so that is when the flush occurs, meaning "Joe3" is written to DB and is also committed.